# Spring Boot Lambda Startup multiple times at the cold start

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I'm writing small Data downloading service function using Spring Boot 2.7. I deployed it in the AWS lambda function. At the cold starting each time it initializes twice as shown in the image below.

[image]

Here is the `lambderHandler.java`

```
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, String> {
    
        private static final ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DataDownloaderService.class);
    
        @Override
        public String handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
            context.getLogger().log("Input: " + event);
            if (!event.getRecords().isEmpty()) {
                SQSEvent.SQSMessage firstRecord = event.getRecords().get(0);
                String eventBody = firstRecord.getBody();
                if (eventBody != null) {
                    ProductDownloadService productDownloadService = applicationContext.getBean(ProductDownloadServiceImpl.class);
                    try {
                        productDownloadService.downloadProductData(JsonUtil.getUserInfo(eventBody));
                        return "Successfully processed";
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return "Error in data downloading: " + e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }
            return "Data download not success";
        }
 }
```

Here is the `DataDownloaderService.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.*"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.test.*"})
public class DataDownloaderService {

}
```

Why spring boot lambda function initialize multiple times at the cold start? Did I have some misconfiguration here or is it a bug?

Comment: Check monitoring for Lambda. Do you see nonzero errors count? Lambda can run you code several times as retry to an error.

Comment: A Lamda function that uses RequestHandler can be a POJO - no need to introduce Spring Boot APIs in the Java logic of a Lambda function. Where did you get this use case from?

Comment: I agree with @smac2020.  Running SpringBoot which is a server inside of a Lambda which is also a type of server makes zero sense.

Comment: @smac2020 Here I used spring boot because I used JPA repositories. After downloading data, it needs to be uploaded to DB. After completing that process the service will send a message to SQS. Hoping it helps to reduce boilerplate codes.
Is there any proper way to achieve this without using Spring Boot?

Comment: Spring Boot is not a server. It can be, but doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to fix this issue from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/issues/210).

Here is the workaround for the above code.

```
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, String> {

private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

/**
 * Entry point in the lambda function
 * @param event
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
@Override
public String handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
    return initDataDownloaderService(event, context);
}

/**
 * initialize application context and Data downloader service
 *
 * @param event
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
private String initDataDownloaderService(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
    if (applicationContext == null) {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DataDownloaderService.class);
    }
    context.getLogger().log("Input: " + event);
    if (!event.getRecords().isEmpty()) {
        SQSEvent.SQSMessage firstRecord = event.getRecords().get(0);
        String eventBody = firstRecord.getBody();
        if (eventBody != null) {
            ProductDownloadService productDownloadService = applicationContext.getBean(ProductDownloadServiceImpl.class);
            try {
                productDownloadService.downloadProductData(JsonUtil.getUserInfo(eventBody));
                return "Successfully processed";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Error in data downloading: " + e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    return "Data download not success";
}
```

}